# what is 'linesize alignment' meaning?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm following ffmpeg tutorial in http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html.

I have just found that `avpicture_get_size` function is deprecated.

So I have checked ffmpeg's document(https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/group__lavu__picture.html#ga24a67963c3ae0054a2a4bab35930e694) and found substitute `av_image_get_buffer_size`.

But I can't understand `align` parameter meaning 'linesize alignment'......

What is it meaning?

Comment: probably you can get the linesize using function [`av_image_get_linesize`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/group__lavu__picture.html#ga8eddd074d5eb6a235591013675ac1055) . I dont know anything about this library, just did ctrl+f for linesize on the same page. It seems to be some sort of internal alignment requirement based on format/dimensions

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if this question gets closed by the community. Welcome to SO /s.

Comment: Thanks for the humor @PreetKukreti. :-)

Comment: `PATH_TO_INSTALL_DIR/share/ffmpeg/examples/hw_decode.c`:
`size = av_image_get_buffer_size(tmp_frame->format, tmp_frame->width, tmp_frame->height, 1);`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Some parts of FFmpeg, notably libavcodec, require aligned linesizes[], which means that it requires:

```
assert(linesize[0] % 32 == 0);
assert(linesize[1] % 32 == 0);
assert(linesize[2] % 32 == 0);
```

This allows it to use fast/aligned SIMD routines (for example SSE2/AVX2 `movdqa` or `vmovdqa` instructions) for data access instead of their slower unaligned counterparts.

The `align` parameter to this `av_image_get_buffer_size` function is this line alignment, and you need it because the size of the buffer is affected by it. E.g., the size of a Y plane in a YUV buffer isn't actually width * height, it's linesize[0] * height. You'll see that (especially for image sizes that are not a multiple of 16 or 32), as you increase `align` to higher powers of 2, the return value slowly increases.

Practically speaking, if you're going to use this picture as output buffer for calls to e.g. `avcodec_decode_video2`, this should be 32. For swscale/avfilter, I believe there is no absolute requirement, but you're recommended to still make it 32.

Comment: Why only 32? Modern SIMD routines are made for 128 or even 256 bit operations. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: 256 / 8 = 32. It's in bytes, not bits.

Comment: Very well written and explained!

Comment: Just a note: if you need to convert the aligned data to nonaligned (e.g. to output them to a raw buffer for external processing or to a file), use `av_image_copy(unalignedFrame->data, unalignedFrame->linesize, const_cast<const uint8_t **>(alignedFrame->data), alignedFrame->linesize, pix_fmt, width, height)` where `alignedFrame` and `unalignedFrame` are frames with the same pixel format but different alignments.

Answer (score 11):

**My practice：**

**1**.**avpicture** deprecated problem, I replace avpicture functions with **AVFrame** & **imgutils** functions. code sample:

```
   //AVPicture           _picture;
   AVFrame             *_pictureFrame;
   uint8_t             *_pictureFrameData;
```

...

```
//_pictureValid = avpicture_alloc(&_picture,
//                                AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
//                               _videoCodecCtx->width,
//                               _videoCodecCtx->height) == 0;

_pictureFrame = av_frame_alloc();
_pictureFrame->width = _videoCodecCtx->width;
_pictureFrame->height = _videoCodecCtx->height;
_pictureFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;

int size = av_image_get_buffer_size(_pictureFrame->format,
                                    _pictureFrame->width,
                                    _pictureFrame->height,
                                    1);

//dont forget to free _pictureFrameData at last                                    
_pictureFrameData = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(size);

 av_image_fill_arrays(_pictureFrame->data,
                      _pictureFrame->linesize,
                      _pictureFrameData,
                      _pictureFrame->format,
                      _pictureFrame->width,
                      _pictureFrame->height,
                      1);
```

...

```
if (_pictureFrame) {
    av_free(_pictureFrame);
    if (_pictureFrameData) {
        free(_pictureFrameData);
    }
}
```

**2.align parameter**

first I set **align** to **32**, but for some video streams it did not work, cause distorted images. Then I set it to **16**(*my environment : mac, Xcode, iPhone6*), the some streams works well. But at last i set **align** to **1**, for I have found [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/1.2/group__lavc__picture.html)

```
Fill in the AVPicture fields, always assume a linesize alignment of 1.
```

Comment: So finally how to calculate `align` properly for all video files?

Comment: Would be nice if ffmpeg at some point in time will clean out this question :O

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the definition of [avpicture_get_size](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/avpicture_8c_source.html#l00052) in version 3.2 you see the following code:

```
int avpicture_get_size(enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt, int width, int height)
{
    return av_image_get_buffer_size(pix_fmt, width, height, 1);
}
```

It simply calls the suggested function: `av_image_get_buffer_size` with the `align` parameter set to `1`. I did not go further to find out the full significance of why `1` is used for the depreciated function. As usual with ffmpeg, one can probably figure it out by reading the right code and enough code (with some code experiments).