# Decoding MediaRecorder produced webm stream

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, webm, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to decode a video stream from the browser using the ffmpeg API. The stream is produced by the webcam and recorded with MediaRecorder as webm format. What I ultimately need is a vector of opencv cv::Mat objects for further processing.

I have written a C++ webserver using the uWebsocket library. The video stream is sent via websocket from the browser to the server once per second. On the server, I append the received data to my custom buffer and decode it with the ffmpeg API.

If I just save the data on the disk and later I play it with a media player, it works fine. So, whatever the browser sends is a valid video.

I do not think that I correctly understand how should the custom IO behave with network streaming as nothing seems to be working.

The custom buffer:

```cpp
 struct Buffer
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> data;
        int currentPos = 0;
    };
```

The readAVBuffer method for custom IO

```cpp
int MediaDecoder::readAVBuffer(void* opaque, uint8_t* buf, int buf_size)
{
    MediaDecoder::Buffer* mbuf = (MediaDecoder::Buffer*)opaque;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<buf_size;i++)
    {
        int index = i + mbuf->currentPos;
        if(index >= (int)mbuf->data.size())
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
        buf[i] = mbuf->data.at(index);
    }
    if(count > 0) mbuf->currentPos+=count;

    std::cout << "read : "<<count<<" "<<mbuf->currentPos<<", buff size:"<<mbuf->data.size() << std::endl;
    if(count <= 0) return AVERROR(EAGAIN); //is this error that should be returned? It cannot be EOF since we're not done yet, most likely
    return count;
}
```

The big decode method, that's supposed to return whatever frames it could read

```cpp
std::vector<cv::Mat> MediaDecoder::decode(const char* data, size_t length)
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;
    //add data to the buffer
    for(size_t i=0;i<length;i++) {
        buf.data.push_back(data[i]);
    }

    //do not invoke the decoders until we have 1MB of data
    if(((buf.data.size() - buf.currentPos) < 1*1024*1024) && !initializedCodecs) return frames;

    std::cout << "decoding data length "<<length<<std::endl;

    if(!initializedCodecs) //initialize ffmpeg objects. Custom I/O, format, decoder, etc.
    {       
        //these are just members of the class 
        avioCtxPtr = std::unique_ptr<AVIOContext,avio_context_deleter>(
                    avio_alloc_context((uint8_t*)av_malloc(4096),4096,0,&buf,&readAVBuffer,nullptr,nullptr),
                    avio_context_deleter());
        if(!avioCtxPtr)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not create IO buffer" << std::endl;
            return frames;
        }                

        fmt_ctx = std::unique_ptr<AVFormatContext,avformat_context_deleter>(avformat_alloc_context(),
                                                                          avformat_context_deleter());
        fmt_ctx->pb = avioCtxPtr.get();
        fmt_ctx->flags |= AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO ;
        //fmt_ctx->max_analyze_duration = 2 * AV_TIME_BASE; // read 2 seconds of data
        {
            AVFormatContext *fmtCtxRaw = fmt_ctx.get();            
            if (avformat_open_input(&fmtCtxRaw, "", nullptr, nullptr) < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Could not open movie" << std::endl;
                return frames;
            }
        }
        if (avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx.get(), nullptr) < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Could not find stream information" << std::endl;
            return frames;
        }
        if((video_stream_idx = av_find_best_stream(fmt_ctx.get(), AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, nullptr, 0)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not find video stream" << std::endl;
            return frames;
        }
        AVStream *video_stream = fmt_ctx->streams[video_stream_idx];
        AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(video_stream->codecpar->codec_id);

        video_dec_ctx = std::unique_ptr<AVCodecContext,avcodec_context_deleter> (avcodec_alloc_context3(dec),
                                                                              avcodec_context_deleter());
        if (!video_dec_ctx)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to allocate the video codec context" << std::endl;
            return frames;
        }
        avcodec_parameters_to_context(video_dec_ctx.get(),video_stream->codecpar);
        video_dec_ctx->thread_count = 1;
       /* video_dec_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
        video_dec_ctx->frame_skip_threshold = 10;*/

        AVDictionary *opts = nullptr;
        av_dict_set(&opts, "refcounted_frames", "1", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "deadline", "1", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "auto-alt-ref", "0", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "lag-in-frames", "1", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "rc_lookahead", "1", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "drop_frame", "1", 0);
        av_dict_set(&opts, "error-resilient", "1", 0);

        int width = video_dec_ctx->width;
        videoHeight = video_dec_ctx->height;

        if(avcodec_open2(video_dec_ctx.get(), dec, &opts) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open the video codec context" << std::endl;
            return frames;
        }

        AVPixelFormat  pFormat = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;
        img_convert_ctx = std::unique_ptr<SwsContext,swscontext_deleter>(sws_getContext(width, videoHeight,
                                         video_dec_ctx->pix_fmt,   width, videoHeight, pFormat,
                                         SWS_BICUBIC, nullptr, nullptr,nullptr),swscontext_deleter());

        frame = std::unique_ptr<AVFrame,avframe_deleter>(av_frame_alloc(),avframe_deleter());
        frameRGB = std::unique_ptr<AVFrame,avframe_deleter>(av_frame_alloc(),avframe_deleter());


        int numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(pFormat, width, videoHeight,32 /*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678041/what-is-linesize-alignment-meaning*/);
        std::unique_ptr<uint8_t,avbuffer_deleter> imageBuffer((uint8_t *) av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t)),avbuffer_deleter());
        av_image_fill_arrays(frameRGB->data,frameRGB->linesize,imageBuffer.get(),pFormat,width,videoHeight,32);
        frameRGB->width = width;
        frameRGB->height = videoHeight;

        initializedCodecs = true;
    }    
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = nullptr;
    pkt.size = 0;

    int read_frame_return = 0;
    while ( (read_frame_return=av_read_frame(fmt_ctx.get(), &pkt)) >= 0)
    {
        readFrame(&frames,&pkt,video_dec_ctx.get(),frame.get(),img_convert_ctx.get(),
                  videoHeight,frameRGB.get());
        //if(cancelled) break;
    }
    avioCtxPtr->eof_reached = 0;
    avioCtxPtr->error = 0;


    //flush
   // readFrame(frames.get(),nullptr,video_dec_ctx.get(),frame.get(),
     //         img_convert_ctx.get(),videoHeight,frameRGB.get());

    avioCtxPtr->eof_reached = 0;
    avioCtxPtr->error = 0;

    if(frames->size() <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "buffer pos: "<<buf.currentPos<<", buff size:"<<buf.data.size()
                  <<",read_frame_return:"<<read_frame_return<< std::endl;
    }

    return frames;
}
```

What I would expect to happen would be for a continuous extraction of cv::Mat frames as I feed it more and more data. What actually happens is that after the the buffer is fully read I see:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x507b450] Read error at pos. 1278266 (0x13813a)
[matroska,webm @ 0x507b450] Seek to desired resync point failed. Seeking to earliest point available instead.
```

And then no more bytes are read from the buffer even if later I increase the size of it.

There is something terribly wrong I'm doing here and I don't understand what.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to do the reading of the incoming data and actual decoding in a different thread. The read method, however, will just block if there are no more bytes available, waiting until anything is coming.

When new bytes are arriving, they're added to the buffer and the conditional_variable signals the waiting thread to wake up and start reading data again from the buffer.

It works well enough.