# How does FFmpeg calculate linesize alignment?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264

I am new to video encoding. I am using FFmpeg library to decode [the H.264 frame](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/ffmpeg-decoder/637637760230407715). I have the below C++ code (full code is [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/ffmpeg-decoder/main.cpp)):

```cpp
AVCodecContext *context = create_codec_context();
AVFrame *decoded_frame = av_frame_alloc();
avcodec_send_packet(context, encoded_packet);
avcodec_receive_frame(context, decoded_frame);

std::cout << decoded_frame->width << "\n"; // prints 1620, as expected
std::cout << decoded_frame->linesize[0] << "\n"; // prints 1664!
```

What looks strange to me is the `linesize` of the decoded frame. Although the `width` of the frame is `1620`, the `linesize[0]` is `1664`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682306/1862286), the `linesize` is calculated taking alignment into consideration. In order to get `1664` from `1620`, one should apply `64` as an alignment to the initial width.

My question is, where does this `64` alignment come from? Searching through FFmpeg code did not give any results. Does the encoded frame itself already have this information?

If afterwards I decide to "flatten" the decoded frame into a one-dimensional array using [av_image_copy_to_buffer()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavu__picture.html#ga6f8576f1ef0c2d9a9f7c5ac7f9a28c52), what alignment should I use? Should it also be `64`?