# FFMPEG convert YCbCr to RGB using sws_scale

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rgb, yuv, libav

I am learning how to use FFMPEG from this [tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial). I am trying to work with RGB images instead of greyscale images. I know I have to call sws_scale but I do not know how to call it correctly inside of my decode function. When I run my code, I get the error "[swscaler @ 0x55a8e7dcbdc0] bad dst image pointers.How should I pass my frame to sws_scale so that it works?
"

```
sws_scale(sws_ctx,(unsigned char const * const *)(frame->data),(frame->linesize),
            0,codecContext->height,pFrameRGB->data,pFrameRGB->linesize);
```

This is the structure of my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

//gcc a.c -o a.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs libavformat libavcodec libswresample libswscale libavutil` && ./a.o

void ProcessArray(char *singleLine,int length)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < length; i++)
    {
        singleLine[i];
    }
}

void save_gray_frame(unsigned char *buf,int wrap,int xsize,int ysize, char *filename)
{
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    printf("\n\nWrap: %d\n\n", wrap);
    f = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(f,"P5\n%d %d\n%d\n",xsize,ysize,255);
    for(i = 0; i < ysize; i++)
    {
        unsigned char *ch = (buf+i*wrap);
        ProcessArray(ch,xsize);
        fwrite(ch,1,xsize,f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}


int decode_packet(AVPacket *packet, AVCodecContext *codecContext, AVFrame *frame,AVFrame *pFrameRGB,struct SwsContext *sws_ctx)
{
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet);
    if(response < 0)
    {
        printf("Error sending packet to decoder");
        return response;
    }
    while(response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, frame);
        if(response == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        {   //Not data memory for frame, have to free and get more data
            av_frame_unref(frame);
            av_freep(frame);
            break;
        }
        if(response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            printf("Error AVERROR_EOF");
            break;
        }
        else if(response < 0)
        {
            printf("Error receiving frame: %s", av_err2str(response));
            av_frame_unref(frame);
            av_freep(frame);
            return response;
        }
        if(response >= 0)
        {
            printf(" Frame %d(type = %c, size = %d bytes, format = %d) pts %ld keyFrame %d [DTS %d]",
            codecContext->frame_number, av_get_picture_type_char(frame->pict_type),
            frame->pkt_size, frame->format, frame->pts, frame->key_frame, frame->coded_picture_number);
            
            int numBytes = (frame->pkt_size) * 3;
            sws_scale(sws_ctx,(unsigned char const * const *)(frame->data),(frame->linesize),
            0,codecContext->height,pFrameRGB->data,pFrameRGB->linesize);
            unsigned char *bu = malloc(numBytes);
            char frame_filename[1024];
            snprintf(frame_filename, sizeof(frame_filename), "%s-%d.pgm","frame", codecContext->frame_number);
            if(frame->format != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
            {
                printf("Maybe not grayscale generated");
            }
            save_gray_frame(frame->data[0],frame->linesize[0],frame->width,frame->height, frame_filename);
        }
        
    }
}



int main()
{
    char *fileName = "sample.mp4";
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;
    
    if(!formatContext)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory for format context");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(avformat_open_input(&formatContext, fileName, NULL,NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open file");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Format: %s, duration %ld, bitrate: %ld\n",formatContext->iformat->name,
    formatContext->duration,formatContext->bit_rate);
    
    if(avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to get stream info");
        return -1;
    }
    
    AVCodec *codec = NULL;
    AVCodecParameters *codecParameters = NULL;
    int videoStreamIndex  = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < formatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVCodecParameters *localCodecParameters = NULL;
        localCodecParameters = formatContext->streams[i]->codecpar;
        printf("Time base before open coded %d %d\n", formatContext->streams[i]->time_base.num,formatContext->streams[i]->time_base.den);
        printf("Frame rate before open coded %d %d\n", formatContext->streams[i]->r_frame_rate.num, formatContext->streams[i]->r_frame_rate.den);
        printf("Start time %"PRId64,formatContext->streams[i]->start_time);
        printf("\nDuration %"PRId64,formatContext->streams[i]->duration);
    
        AVCodec *localCodec = NULL;
        localCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(localCodecParameters->codec_id);
        if(localCodec == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: Unsupported codec");
            continue;
        }
        if(localCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            if(videoStreamIndex == -1)
            {
                videoStreamIndex = i;
                codec = localCodec;
                codecParameters = localCodecParameters;
            }
            printf("Video Resolution: %d %d",localCodecParameters->width, localCodecParameters->height);
        }
        else if(localCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            printf("Audio: %d channels, sample rate %d",localCodecParameters->channels, localCodecParameters->sample_rate);
        }
        printf("\nCodec :%s ID %d bit_rate %ld", localCodec->name, localCodec->id,localCodecParameters->bit_rate);
    }
    
    if(videoStreamIndex == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: File does not contain video stream");
        return -1;
    }
    
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if(!codecContext)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for AVCodecContext");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, codecParameters) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to copy codec paramters to codec context");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to open codec throught avcodec_open2");
    }
    
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if(!frame)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate moemory for AVFrame");
        return -1;
    }
     AVPacket *packet = av_packet_alloc();
     if(!packet)
     {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for AVPacket");
        return -1;
     }
     
     int response = 0;
     int howManypacketsToProcess = 5;
     int frameFinished = 0;
     
     sws_ctx = sws_getContext
     (
        codecContext->width,
        codecContext->height,
        codecContext->pix_fmt,
        codecContext->width,
        codecContext->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
        SWS_BILINEAR,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL        
     );
     AVFrame *pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

     while(av_read_frame(formatContext,packet) >= 0)
     {  
        if(packet->stream_index == videoStreamIndex)
        {
            printf("\nAVPacket->pts %"PRId64, packet->pts);
            response = decode_packet(packet, codecContext, frame,pFrameRGB, sws_ctx);
            if(response < 0)
            {
                printf("\nError response < 0\n");
                break;
            }
            if(--howManypacketsToProcess <=0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(packet);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about FFMPEG, but you're not allocating any space for `sws_ctx`. If `decode_packet` --> `sws_scale` is expecting that to point to valid memory, it's not.

Comment: I do this elsewhere.

Comment: Is it possible that you do it _elsewhere_ wrongly? Let us see how you do it, e.g. a reproducible example would be nice. The error message _bad dst image pointers_ does state it clearly, that there is something wrong with your `pFrameRGB` data.

Comment: I added my entire program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if using `AVFrame` for storing the output is the best practice.
In case we are using `AVFrame`, we have to initialize at least some of the fields.

We may base the solution on the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale), but few of the used functions are deprecated.
Assume we are using a newer version of FFmpeg libraries.

---

We may use the following allocation stages after `AVFrame *pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();`:

- Get buffer sized (allocated number of bytes) for storing the output frame:

  ```
   int num_bytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height, 1);
  ```
- Allocate the output buffer:

  ```
   unsigned char* frame_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(num_bytes);
  ```
- Fill `pFrameRGB->data` and `pFrameRGB->linesize`.
  `pFrameRGB->data[0]` is "filled" with `frame_buffer` (pointer to allocated buffer).
  `pFrameRGB->linesize[0]` is filled with `linesize` (usually `width*3`).

  ```
   av_image_fill_arrays(pFrameRGB->data,       //uint8_t *dst_data[4], 
                        pFrameRGB->linesize,   //int dst_linesize[4],
                        frame_buffer,          //const uint8_t * src,
                        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,      //enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
                        codecContext->width,   //int width, 
                        codecContext->height,  //int height,
                        1);                    //int align);
  ```
- Set `pFrameRGB->width` and `pFrameRGB->height`:

  ```
   pFrameRGB->width = codecContext->width;
   pFrameRGB->height = codecContext->height;
  ```

---

Executing `sws_scale` and checking status:

```
response = sws_scale(sws_ctx, (unsigned char const * const *)(frame->data), (frame->linesize),
                     0, codecContext->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

if (response <= 0)
{
    printf("Error: sws_scale status = %d\n", response);
}
```

---

Complete code (using `bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4` from the [tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial) as input):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>  // <-- Requiered for av_image_get_buffer_size

//gcc a.c -o a.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs libavformat libavcodec libswresample libswscale libavutil` && ./a.o

void ProcessArray(char *singleLine,int length)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < length; i++)
    {
        singleLine[i];
    }
}

void save_gray_frame(unsigned char *buf,int wrap,int xsize,int ysize, char *filename)
{
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    printf("\n\nWrap: %d\n\n", wrap);
    f = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(f,"P5\n%d %d\n%d\n",xsize,ysize,255);
    for(i = 0; i < ysize; i++)
    {
        unsigned char *ch = (buf+i*wrap);
        ProcessArray(ch,xsize);
        fwrite(ch,1,xsize,f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}


void save_rgb_frame(unsigned char* buf, int wrap, int xsize, int ysize, char* filename)
{
    FILE* f;
    int i;
    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    fprintf(f, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", xsize, ysize);

    for (i = 0; i < ysize; i++)
    {
        unsigned char* ch = (buf + i * wrap);
        //ProcessArray(ch, xsize);
        fwrite(ch, 1, xsize*3, f);  //Write 3 bytes per pixel.
    }

    fclose(f);
}



int decode_packet(AVPacket *packet, AVCodecContext *codecContext, AVFrame *frame,AVFrame *pFrameRGB,struct SwsContext *sws_ctx)
{
    int response = avcodec_send_packet(codecContext, packet);
    if(response < 0)
    {
        printf("Error sending packet to decoder");
        return response;
    }
    while(response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(codecContext, frame);
        if(response == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
        {   //Not data memory for frame, have to free and get more data
            av_frame_unref(frame);
            av_freep(frame);
            break;
        }
        if(response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            printf("Error AVERROR_EOF");
            break;
        }
        else if(response < 0)
        {
            printf("Error receiving frame: %s", av_err2str(response));
            av_frame_unref(frame);
            av_freep(frame);
            return response;
        }
        if(response >= 0)
        {
            printf(" Frame %d(type = %c, size = %d bytes, format = %d) pts %ld keyFrame %d [DTS %d]",
            codecContext->frame_number, av_get_picture_type_char(frame->pict_type),
            frame->pkt_size, frame->format, frame->pts, frame->key_frame, frame->coded_picture_number);
            
            //int numBytes = (frame->pkt_size) * 3;

            response = sws_scale(sws_ctx, (unsigned char const * const *)(frame->data), (frame->linesize),
                                 0, codecContext->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);

            if (response <= 0)
            {
                printf("Error: sws_scale status = %d\n", response);
            }

            //unsigned char *bu = malloc(numBytes);
            char frame_filename[1024];
            snprintf(frame_filename, sizeof(frame_filename), "%s-%d.ppm","frame", codecContext->frame_number);
            if(frame->format != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P)
            {
                printf("Maybe not grayscale generated");
            }
            //save_gray_frame(frame->data[0],frame->linesize[0],frame->width,frame->height, frame_filename);

            //Write RBG output to PPM image file
            save_rgb_frame(pFrameRGB->data[0], pFrameRGB->linesize[0], pFrameRGB->width, pFrameRGB->height, frame_filename);
        }
        
    }
}



int main()
{
    const char *fileName = "bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4";
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = NULL;
    
    if(!formatContext)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory for format context");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(avformat_open_input(&formatContext, fileName, NULL,NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open file");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Format: %s, duration %ld, bitrate: %ld\n",formatContext->iformat->name,
    formatContext->duration,formatContext->bit_rate);
    
    if(avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to get stream info");
        return -1;
    }
    
    AVCodec *codec = NULL;
    AVCodecParameters *codecParameters = NULL;
    int videoStreamIndex  = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < formatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        AVCodecParameters *localCodecParameters = NULL;
        localCodecParameters = formatContext->streams[i]->codecpar;
        printf("Time base before open coded %d %d\n", formatContext->streams[i]->time_base.num,formatContext->streams[i]->time_base.den);
        printf("Frame rate before open coded %d %d\n", formatContext->streams[i]->r_frame_rate.num, formatContext->streams[i]->r_frame_rate.den);
        printf("Start time %"PRId64,formatContext->streams[i]->start_time);
        printf("\nDuration %"PRId64,formatContext->streams[i]->duration);
    
        AVCodec *localCodec = NULL;
        localCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(localCodecParameters->codec_id);
        if(localCodec == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: Unsupported codec");
            continue;
        }
        if(localCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            if(videoStreamIndex == -1)
            {
                videoStreamIndex = i;
                codec = localCodec;
                codecParameters = localCodecParameters;
            }
            printf("Video Resolution: %d %d",localCodecParameters->width, localCodecParameters->height);
        }
        else if(localCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            printf("Audio: %d channels, sample rate %d",localCodecParameters->channels, localCodecParameters->sample_rate);
        }
        printf("\nCodec :%s ID %d bit_rate %ld", localCodec->name, localCodec->id,localCodecParameters->bit_rate);
    }
    
    if(videoStreamIndex == -1)
    {
        printf("Error: File does not contain video stream");
        return -1;
    }
    
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if(!codecContext)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for AVCodecContext");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, codecParameters) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to copy codec paramters to codec context");
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("failed to open codec throught avcodec_open2");
    }
    
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if(!frame)
    {
        printf("Failed to allocate moemory for AVFrame");
        return -1;
    }
     AVPacket *packet = av_packet_alloc();
     if(!packet)
     {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for AVPacket");
        return -1;
     }
     
     int response = 0;
     int howManypacketsToProcess = 8;
     int frameFinished = 0;
     
     sws_ctx = sws_getContext
     (
        codecContext->width,
        codecContext->height,
        codecContext->pix_fmt,
        codecContext->width,
        codecContext->height,
        AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
        SWS_BILINEAR,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL        
     );


     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     AVFrame *pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

     //int num_bytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale
     //avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pFrameRGB, frame_buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height);  //deprecated use av_image_fill_arrays() instead.

     int num_bytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, codecContext->width, codecContext->height, 1); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678041/what-is-linesize-alignment-meaning

     unsigned char* frame_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(num_bytes);

     response = av_image_fill_arrays(pFrameRGB->data,       //uint8_t *dst_data[4], 
                                     pFrameRGB->linesize,   //int dst_linesize[4],
                                     frame_buffer,          //const uint8_t * src,
                                     AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,      //enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmt,
                                     codecContext->width,   //int width, 
                                     codecContext->height,  //int height,
                                     1);                    //int align);

     if (response < 0)
     {
         printf("av_image_fill_arrays Failed, response = %d\n", response);
     }

     pFrameRGB->width = codecContext->width;
     pFrameRGB->height = codecContext->height;
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


     while(av_read_frame(formatContext,packet) >= 0)
     {  
        if(packet->stream_index == videoStreamIndex)
        {
            printf("\nAVPacket->pts %"PRId64, packet->pts);
            response = decode_packet(packet, codecContext, frame,pFrameRGB, sws_ctx);
            if(response < 0)
            {
                printf("\nError response < 0\n");
                break;
            }
            if(--howManypacketsToProcess <=0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(packet);
     }

     av_free(frame_buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Sample output image (resized):
[image]

Comment: This is excellent! Should be the accepted answer for recent (2022) ffmpeg 5.0.